# Why does my recursion fall through?

Tags: java, recursion

My recursive function is falling through in my program. I am making a method that constructs a relatively simple object array and populates them with certain values. i.e. object 1 has these values 3,2,5,6,7, object 2 has these values; 4,5,6,4,5. and so on

the recursion comes in when I have different parts of the method that do different things to the function. as shown below:

```
objectConstructor(Object foo, int switcherVar){
    if(switcherVar == 1){
        //terminating condition leave method
        return 1;
    } else {
        if(switcherVar == 2){
        //do something
        objectConstructor(object foo, 1)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I check my return value i get a 0. The stuff that I'm actually doing in the method is unrelated to my recursive function and the function IS re cursing just at the end it falls through when its supposed to jump to the terminating condition. From my understanding the problem is the way I'm formatting my recursive function.

Below is the actual code It's an airplane seat constructor that give values to an airplanes seats, like if it is occupied and whatnot. the above is easier to read but if my syntax is off that might be the problem as well.

```
private int airplaneSeatConstructor(Airplane airplane, String className, int numberOfSeats){
    /*Airplane Seat Creator, loops through the seats and attaches credentials to them based on the type of plane
    * being formed.*/

    //currently only one plane type. 777.
    //777 seat number 257
    //does have a first class section.
    System.out.println("iteration");
    if(className.equals("TERM")){
        return 1;
    }else {
        if (className.equals("FIRST")) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfSeats; x++) {
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setOccupied(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setFirstClass(true);
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setBusinessClass(false);

                if ((x % 4) == 0 || (x % 4) == 3) {
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setWindowseat(true);
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setAisleSeat(false);
                } else {
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setAisleSeat(true);
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setWindowseat(false);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("in first");
            airplaneSeatConstructor(airplane, "BUSINESS", 40);
        }
        if (className.equals("BUSINESS")) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfSeats; x++) {
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setBusinessClass(true);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setFirstClass(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setOccupied(false);
            }
            System.out.println("in business");
            airplaneSeatConstructor(airplane, "ECONOMY", 209);
        }
        if (className.equals("ECONOMY")) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfSeats; x++) {
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[1] + x].setBusinessClass(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[1] + x].setFirstClass(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[1] + x].setOccupied(false);
            }
            System.out.println("in economy");
            airplaneSeatConstructor(airplane, "SPECIAL", 26);
        }
        if (className.equals("SPECIAL")) {
            System.out.println("in special");
            airplaneSeatConstructor(airplane, "TERM", 273);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my print lines all hit but I'm still getting 0 from my return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, whatever recursion you do, in fact, whatever calculation you do is not going to count, since you're finally returning 0 for all cases but the base one (in which you return 1).

```
objectConstructor(Object foo, int switcherVar){
    if(switcherVar == 1){
        //terminating condition leave method
        return 1;
    } else {
        if(switcherVar == 2){
        //do something
        objectConstructor(object foo, 1)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Recursion in your program works this way: you do the first call with switcher == 2, which makes the recursive call whit switcher == 1. But then you discard that result and just return 0.

The correct or logic way of things for doing this is more similar to this:

```
objectConstructor(Object foo, int switcherVar){
    if(switcherVar == 1){
        //terminating condition leave method
        return 1;
    } else {
        if(switcherVar == 2){
        //do something
        return objectConstructor(object foo, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

However, looking closely to your code, I think that you are substituting sequence by recursion. I would refactor (i.e., divide the code of) your function by classes of seats, and make the needed calls. Recursion is not needed *at all* in your code. See below:

```
private void airplaneSeatConstructorFirstClass(Airplane airplane, int numberOfSeats)
{
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfSeats; x++) {
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setOccupied(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setFirstClass(true);
                airplane.getSeats()[x].setBusinessClass(false);

                if ((x % 4) == 0 || (x % 4) == 3) {
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setWindowseat(true);
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setAisleSeat(false);
                } else {
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setAisleSeat(true);
                    airplane.getSeats()[x].setWindowseat(false);
                }
            }
}

private void airplaneSeatConstructorBussinessClass(Airplane airplane, int numberOfSeats)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfSeats; x++) {
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setBusinessClass(true);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setFirstClass(false);
                airplane.getSeats()[airplane.getNumberOfSeatsPerClass()[0] + x].setOccupied(false);
            }
}
```

...and so on.

Now you just have to call:

```
airplaneSeatConstructorFirstClass( airplane, 80 );
airplaneSeatConstructorBussinessClass( airplane, 40 );
```

As you can see is far easier (unless I'm missing something big).

Comment: the only reason why I'm using recursion is to understand it better. but your way makes much more sense. My thought process was to have one function to set up the initial seat values. Thank you this helps out with the overall design of my code.

Comment: also, when i try to remove my return 0 at the end. Intellij is giving me an error.

Comment: IntelliJ complains of you remove the "return 0" at the end because you have stated that your functions return an integer. I also copied&pasted and did not realise about that. If you don't need a value to return from your functions, just put "void" instead of the return type.

Comment: can i return an int on a void method in Java? 

To understand a little better, would there be a more appropriate situation to re curse? Is the an example of what kind of situation I should be looking for that would be ideal for recursion in your opinion?

Comment: No, you cannot return anything in a void method in Java. An example of a recursive function could be; public long factorial(long x) { if ( x == 1 ) return 1; else return x * factorial( x - 1 ); } This method calculates the factorial of a number, and is a case in which recursion makes sense.
My advice for you is a good reference book, such as thinking in Java, from Bruce Eckel: http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that this

```
objectConstructor(object foo, 1);
```

returns 1.

After that you do `return 0`. Of course the whole thing will return 0.

Maybe you should

```
return objectConstructor(object foo, 1);
```

Comment: this one gave me the correct result :) Basically could we say that using the return statement in a recursive function would be necessary if our recursive function had a terminating value such as mine.